# How to use a grok to extract Service url component out of log

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to use a grok expression to extract the service url and time out of the expression posted below, but because there's multiple urls - my solution often retrieves the wrong url - so its not really consistent.

I've tried `%{URIPATH:Path1}%{SPACE}%{URIPATH:ServiceURI}%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:time}`

This doesn't work at all , but if I remove the `{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:time}` - it gives me the result I'm looking for but it's not consistent with the other logs as they have a different format. So I'm trying to find a consistent way of getting the time, and Service URL out of a log.

> Jun 12 04:27:35    1560306455  INCOMING: information 22.244.42.41 Jun 12 04:27:22 DPPRD01 [host_services][0x80e0013a][mpgw][info] source-https(IMS_SSL_29982): trans(2797190703)[12.6.1.16]: Received HTTP/1.1 POST for /services/NHgetInternetLimitsV1 from 10.6.17.166

**What I expect is something like**

> time : Jun 12 04:27:35
>   service : NHgetInternetLimitsV1 or /services/NHgetInternetLimitsV1

Comment: What about `%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:time}.*POST for %{URIPATH:ServiceURI}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:time}.*POST for %{URIPATH:ServiceURI}
```

It will extract

```
{
  "time": [
    [
      "Jun 12 04:27:35"
    ]
  ],
  "ServiceURI": [
    [
      "/services/NHgetInternetLimitsV1"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Note that due to the `.*POST for` part, the last Service URI after `POST for` substring will be matched.